# "for" loop with IEnumerator coroutine containing a yied return not looping

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, yield-return

I am selecting data from a database and then assigning that data to values in an array in my unity project using c#. The database is accessed with php scripts and my game calls the scripts on the server. My plan is to increment the ship number and use the same script calling on a different ship in the database. This is all working well except my loop in c#, which executes only once. Here is my code. `shipsAllowed` is set at 2 right now for testing purposes and there is record for this ship in the database. So what am I doing wrong, seems straight forward but is not working for me. Thanks for any help.

```
public void AddShipsToShipsArray()
{
    for (int x = 1; x < ShipsAllowed; x++)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetShipInfoFromDB(x));
    }
}

IEnumerator GetShipInfoFromDB(int x)
{

    shipInfoUrl = "http://localhost/fishwar/GetShipInfo.php?shipnum=" + x + "&id=" + accountNumber;
    WWW shipInfoWWW = new WWW(shipInfoUrl);
    yield return shipInfoWWW;
    shipinfoRawString = shipInfoWWW.text;

    Dictionary<string, object> shipInfo = MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(shipinfoRawString) as Dictionary<string, object>;

    shipArrayPosition = int.Parse((string)shipInfo["array_position"]);
    ships[shipArrayPosition].shipName = (string)shipInfo["ship_name"];
    ships[shipArrayPosition].departureTime = DateTime.Parse((string)shipInfo["departure_time"]);
    ships[shipArrayPosition].isAtSea = bool.Parse((string)shipInfo["is_at_sea"]);
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you tried to create [MCVE] you could have found problem yourself, or at very least made question more targeted (`yield return` has no relation to problem code demonstrates).

Answer (score 4):

Change the exit condition in your loop to use less-than-or-equal-to:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= ShipsAllowed; x++) // Change made on this line.
{
    StartCoroutine(GetShipInfoFromDB(x));
}
```